# 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class in ListFragment

Tags: android, eclipse, listview

I am new to android development. I have created a List View for displaying items in custom formats. I have given code below that I've used in eclipse. But I'm receiving an error while running the application, "Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class in ListFragment".

**This is Activity**

```
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CalllogActivity extends ListFragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
    private CLAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        //ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.CallLogs, R.layout.layout_calllogs);

        ListView lstDetails= (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.lstDtls);
        adapter=new CLAdapter(this);

        lstDetails.setAdapter(adapter);
        lstDetails.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i,
            long l) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item " + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    class CLAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        private Context context;
        String[] CallLogNames;
        String[] CallNo;
        int[] images;
        String[] CallDateTime;

        public CLAdapter(Context context){
            this.context=context;
            CallLogNames = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.CallLogs);
        }

        public CLAdapter(CalllogActivity calllogActivity) {
            CallLogNames = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.CallLogs);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return CallLogNames.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return CallLogNames[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row=null;
            if(convertView==null)
            {
                LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_calllogs, parent, false);
            }
            else    
            {
                row=convertView;
            }

            TextView txtName=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            ImageView imgPhoto=(ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgContact);
            TextView txtNo = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtNo);
            TextView txtDateTime = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtDateTime);

            txtName.setText(CallLogNames[position]);
            //txtNo.setText(CallLogNames[position]);
            //txtDateTime.setText(CallLogNames[position]);
            //imgPhoto.setImageResource(images[position]);
            return row;
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the Fragment XML Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstDtls"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**This is the custom layout I've created for showing in the List**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgContact"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxHeight="60dp"
        android:maxWidth="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/unknown_contact" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgContact"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtNo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgContact"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDateTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `android:id="@+id/lstDtls"` **must be** `android:id="@+id/list"`

Comment: I've tried that one also and declared ListView as "ListView lstDetails= (ListView) getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);". But receiving the same error.

Comment: Have you checked which R. is that.

Comment: I've given a predefined ID("android:id="@android:id/list") now as it is a ListFragment. So I cannot give "R.id.list".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use ListFragment or ListActivity list in your layout has to use predefined id:

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

In your code you can retrieve this list by using

```
ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

ListFragment and ListActivity have hard coded this value and do not work if they cannot find list to use.

Comment: That also I've tried. I have given 'ListView lstDetails= (ListView) getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);'. But receiving the same error.

Comment: you have to change android:id in your layout xml file! I posted correct syntax.

Comment: Yes.. I have changed the id to "android:id="@android:id/list" and declared the list as "ListView lstDetails= (ListView) getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);". But the issue is not resolved. While running the application it is showing that 'Unfortunately the apllication is stopped.'

Comment: Check logs, I guess you are now getting some other error. Also please update your code.

Comment: Yes.. You are right.. Now I'm getting other error. Older one is rectified.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change Id of listView

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>
```

then use `R.id.list` **not** `android.R.id.list`

Comment: I have changed the id to "android:id="@android:id/list" and declared the list as "ListView lstDetails= (ListView) getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);". But the issue is not resolved. While running the application it is showing that 'Unfortunately the apllication is stopped.

Comment: .findViewById(R.id.list); (not **R.** ) you will see an erropr , build and clean the project

Comment: But it is a ListFragment, so it is compulsory to use predefined ID. That is why I've given "android:id="@android:id/list"

Answer (score 0):

To add onto this, it's worth noting that [in the ListFragment spec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle)) it mentions that the listview named 'list' must have either the sibling `android.R.id.empty`, or not be empty.  My issue was that the listview was both empty and didn't have the `empty` sibling.

The fix was to add a textview named empty,

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/list">
</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</TextView>
```